# Display ViewData in View from Controller of asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one action in my controller :

```
public ActionResult ProductSpec()
{
  var pvc = new CMS()
  {
    //blah blah blah
  };
  var count_item = DataContext.GetItemReferences();
  ViewData["ttttt"] = count_item; //8
  return View(pvc);
}
```

And then I display the `ViewData["ttttt"]` in my view, but the result is `System.Collections.Generic.List1[EWeb.Models.Pro]` .

Could anyone tell me how to sovle it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var count_item = DataContext.GetItemReferences().Count;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I missed it. Thanks you so much.